# Scanning multiple files in parallel using clamav > clamd is very slow

Tags: clamav, clam

I am in process of using clamd as a service for scanning multiple files in parallel.

**My workflow:**

- ReadFile on client machine
- Stream data in blocks to clamav service
- Open clamd socket connection and write data on UnixSocket (clamd.ctl) (using clamd.ClamdUnixSocket())

This workflow works perfectly well when I have small files or just a few files being transferred over to my clamav service.

But as number of files in parallel increase, I am observing high write time on clam.ClamdUnixSocket.instream (internally, clamd.ctl unix socket).

*Trying with 32-64 parallel files.*
*I also tried switching to network socket (TCP based) which also gives similar performance.*

```
        #req is HTTP request (python) 
        ipfile = req.stream
        cus = clamd.ClamdUnixSocket()
        scan_res = cus.instream(ipfile)
```

**Questions:**

- Is this a known issue ?
- Are there any configurations which can be tweaked for better performance.

**ClamAV information:**
clamav version: 0.103.8
clamd daemon is installed on linux server
Virus definitions are up to date.